# Prolog findall/3: more than one bag

Tags: prolog, prolog-findall

I'm writing AI for a Fox and Geese type of game. One of my predicates looks like this:

```
moveFox(+PrevState, -NextState, -PegList, +VisitedStates, -NewVisitedStates)
```

It takes a game state and makes a move with a fox. The resulting state is unified with `NextState` and the actual move is unified with `PegList`. Everything works as expected.

I am calculating the utility score for all of the moves' `NextState`. To be able to find the state with the highest utility score, I use `findall/3` to get all states in a list before comparing their utility scores.

```
findall(NextState, moveFox(...), NextStatesList)
```

By finding the maximum utility score I know the `NextState` (as well as its position in the list) with the highest utility score. There is only one problem, currently I haven't written any predicate to infer which move was made to come to `NextState`, e.g.:

```
getMove(+PrevState, +NextState, -PegList)
```

Instead of writing such a predicate, I would much rather use `findall/3` or equivalent. My question is if there is some way to get two different variables in two different lists. I'm thinking like this (if it would have worked):

```
findall([NextState, PegList], moveFox(...), [NextStatesList, MoveList])
```

Could I implement such functionality without having to either run `findall/3` twice (ugly overhead) or write that `getMove(+PrevState, +NextState, -PegList)` predicate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this problem can be tackled building a list of *pairs*, and then separating the elements, like library([pairs](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.18%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/pairs.html%27%29%29)) does

```
...
findall(NextState-PegList, moveFox(...), Pairs),
pairs_keys_values(Pairs, NextStates, Pegs),
...
```

If your Prolog doesn't have pairs_keys_values/3, it's easy to write either with maplist or via a recursive predicate. Here is the maplist way:

```
pkv(K-V, K, V).
pairs_keys_values(Pairs, Keys, Vals) :-
    maplist(pkv, Pairs, Keys, Vals).
```